# Index of element smaller/larger than a float in numpy subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take two `numpy` arrays (`aa, bb`) with possibly different number of sub-arrays (`M1` is not necessarily equal to `M2`) but equal lengths (`N`), and a float (`e_max`)

```
M1, M2, N = np.random.randint(1, 3), np.random.randint(1, 3), 100
e_max = .3
aa = np.random.rand(M1, N)
bb = np.random.rand(M2, N)
```

I need the indexes of all elements that are simultaneously `< e_max` in **all** sub-arrays of `aa, bb` and also its complement; ie, the indexes of those elements that are `>= e_max` in **at least** one sub-array of `aa, bb`.

What's an efficient way to do this with `numpy`?

Comment: By indices, do you mean the row or column indices?

Comment: The column indices if I'm not mistaken (those that run up to `N`)

Comment: IIUC But if there are different number of rows in aa and bb, how could we fulfil the simultaneous criteria?

Comment: The element has to fulfill the condition `< e_max` in all rows of both `a` and `b` to be "accepted". If it is `>= e_max` in **any** of the rows of either `a` or `b`, it is stored as "rejected". Is this not clear in the question? Should I edit this in to make it clear?

Comment: Perhaps I'm mixing up rows with columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC two ways to do so.

With `any` -

```
np.flatnonzero(~((aa>=e_max).any(0) | (bb>=e_max).any(0)))
```

With `all` -

```
np.flatnonzero(((aa<e_max).all(0) & (bb<e_max).all(0)))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you Divakar! For the sake of completeness, the lines you came up with give me the "accepted indexes" (`acpt_idx`). To obtain the complement, I use `np.setdiff1d(np.arange(N), acpt_idx)`.

Comment: @Gabriel Or just swap the `~` there.